# Pre-populate checkboxes in Angular 5

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-forms, dynamicform

In an Angular 5 project, I have a template driven form that is pre-populated by the following array:

```js
let data = [{
    Title: "My Title",
    Description: "My description",
    Value: "my_value",
    Category: "category_name",
    SelectionType: SelectionDisplayType.Checkbox,
    Selected: false
}]
```

Here is the html:

```html
<ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index;">
          <label [for]="item.Title">{{ item.Title }}</label>
          <input ngModel #columnValuesInputs 
            [id]="item.Title" 
            [name]="item.Category" 
            [type]="((item.SelectionType === SelectionType.Checkbox) ? 'checkbox' : 'radio')" 
            [checked]="((item.Selected) ? 'checked' : '')" 
            [value]="item.Value" />
     </li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that all of the input field "value" attributes are being populated **except** for the checkboxes and radio buttons, even though I'm binding the `item.Value` to the `[value]` property. So, when I output the values via `{{ formFilter.value | json }}`, the checkbox and radiobutton values are empty.

Reactive forms are preferable, however I'm restricted to use template-driven forms.

Please can anyone shed light on what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: try using [ngModel]="item.Selected"

Comment: @Krishnanunni Jeevan,I now get a string "false" as the value  when a checkbox is checked. Your solution is close, however not quite right. Preferable initially its  false (boolean or string), then when checked, the value updates to true.(boolean or string), thanks.

Comment: I will write as answer

Answer (score 1):

Personally with the addition of Reactive Forms. I have abandoned ngModel altogether.

```
private form: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit(){
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
     Title: "My Title",
     Description: "My description",
     Value: "my_value",
     Category: "category_name",
     SelectionType: SelectionDisplayType.Checkbox,
     Selected: false
    })
}

<div *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="Value" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes reactive forms are preferable, however Im restricted to template driven forms for this project, sorry forgot to mention that, question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[ngModel]="item.Selected"
```

This is one way binding. If you need to get two way binding(not recommended) use :-

```
[(ngModel)]="item.Selected"
```

This will take care of actions when you check. The other option is to keep one way binding and listen to change of input (has to be handled differently for radio button)

```
[ngModel]="item.Selected"  (click)="item.Selected=!item.Selected"
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-checkbox-69tnvh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: For what reason would you not recommend two way binding in this case?

Comment: Tried [(ngModel)]="item.Selected"...still when i check an option the value is updated from :false to :"false". Also I would like to avoid handling the change of input.

Comment: @vicgoyso,  Is item.Category unique? All inputs should have a unique name . If category is not unique use something like name="item.category_{{i}}".

Comment: @SimonK, just my opinion after seeing advantages of using unidirectional flow of data.  You can always use (ngModelChange)="item.Selected=!item.Selected". But again I could be wrong since I haven't seen the whole project , 2 way binding may be better here

Comment: @Krishnanunni Jeevan, item.Category is unique for checkboxes, however not for radio buttons

Comment: @vicgoyso, I think it is related to change the type  of input dynamically based on condition. Try using ngIf for checkbox and radio button. I have created a link:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-checkbox-69tnvh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
 [checked]="((item.Selected) ? true : false)"
```